# Como posso descobrir o método da requisição http pelo PHP?

Tags: php, http

Eu sei que cada requisição http feita, seja pelo navegador ou outro recurso, envia um determinado método (`GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE` e etc.).

Eu estou pensando em construir uma aplicação Restful com PHP, porém não sei como posso fazer para poder descobrir qual é o método da requisição atual, para poder validá-la.

Caso seja uma requisição `GET` em uma url que aceite apenas `POST`, quero retornar o Erro `405`, que é o `método não aceitável`.

Como saber o método da requisição atual pelo PHP?

Comment: Uma dica útil: Faça um aplicativo simples que dê um var_dump($_REQUEST). Tem bastante coisa útil lá. (-:

Comment: @PerryWerneck `$_REQUEST` ou `$_SERVER`?

Comment: Ops! Nesse caso $_SERVER. (-:

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o seguinte código:

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
  //retorne 405;
}
```